# Direct access to the automatic differentiation inside pyomo

Tags: pyomo, automatic-differentiation

Is it possible to directly access the automatic differentiation module coming with pyomo? By that, I mean, could I compute derivatives of any objective function (defined or not inside pyomo's interface) using pyomo?

Answer (score 0):

Pyomo makes use of the Python sympy package for its current differentiation function.

I believe Jacobian information is also available through the Pynumero contributed package, but I have not personally used that myself.